# something like preprocessors at runtime

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries

In my application, I use new function from library x2.0 which wasn't found in version x1.0 but i want to maintain backward compatibility.

I'm dynamically link with that library, When I used simple if condition to check for the library version before executing the new function it didn't work as during startup the exe searches and resolves all functions as when I'm running the application linked to the old version it gives me error.

at runtime I want the exe checks for the lib version and execute the new function or doesn't execute it according to that version.

Is that possible and if so,

what can I do to achieve this ?

Comment: Is the library too large to create a wrapper around it for your application?

Comment: I'm not in control with the library development, I got it from the internet

Comment: But you can be in control of a wrapper around it.

Comment: well, what do u mean by wrapper ? .. sorry i cant get it

Comment: @becks The usual way is to declare certain contracts (pure virtual interfaces) and test for  them using `dynamic_cast<MyExtendedInterface>`to validate.

Comment: can u please add an example showing that in an answer?

Comment: Is this for a Windows or Linux platform?  Does the user have source for your application so it can be built against that target system's libraries or does the user only have the executable binary?

Comment: both platforms...  the user doesnt have the source code, he just has the exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best answer is to use both implicit and explicit linking for same dll 
and by default loader will load dll and then use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress in your code for APIs that doesn't exist in older versions of library

```
  HINSTANCE hinstLib; //Handle to the DLL
    // MYPROC ProcAddress; //Pointer to the function

   hinstLib = LoadLibrary("x.dll");
   FOO3 myFunc = (FOO3) GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "foo3");
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with backward compatibility with a third party library is to create a wrapper library/source file around it, and making sure that your application never calls any of the functions of the third party library from any other place.

Let's say, you are depending on  a third party library that provides two header files, "foo.h" and "bar.h". In version 1 of the library, the files might look like:

foo.h:

```
void foo1();
int foo2();
```

bar.h:

```
void bar1(int);
int bar2(int);
```

Let's say, they expanded the interface in version 2 and now they look like:

foo.h:

```
void foo1();
int foo2();
double foo3();
```

bar.h:

```
void bar1(int);
int bar2(int);
int bar3(double);
```

In your application, you would like to be able to use `foo3()` and `bar3()` when linking with version 2 of the library but you want to be able to gracefully deal with lack of those functions in version 1 of the library.

You can use the following to accomplish that.

Create a wrapper .h file for the library.

foo_bar_wrapper.h:

```
namespace foo_bar_wrapper
{
    void foo1();
    int foo2();
    double foo3();
    void bar1(int);
    int bar2(int);
    int bar3(double);
}
```

Then, implement them as pass through to the third party library.

foo_bar_wrapper.h:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

namespace foo_bar_wrapper
{
    void foo1() { ::foo1(); }
    int foo2() { return ::foo2(); }
    double foo3() { return ::foo3(); }
    void bar1(int x) { return ::bar1(x); }
    int bar2(int x) { return ::bar2(x); }
    int bar3(double x) { return ::bar3(x); }
}
```

However, since `foo3` and `bar3` are not supported in version 1 of the library, you can use:

```
namespace foo_bar_wrapper
{
    void foo1() { ::foo1(); }
    int foo2() { return ::foo2(); }

    double foo3() 
    {
#if FOO_LIBRARY_VERSION > 1
        return ::foo3();
#else
        // Deal gracefully with version 1
#endif
    }

    void bar1(int x) { return ::bar1(x); }
    int bar2(int x) { return ::bar2(x); }

    int bar3(double x)
    {
#if FOO_LIBRARY_VERSION > 1
       return ::bar3(x);
#else
        // Deal gracefully with version 1
#endif
    }

}
```

Make sure you define `FOO_LIBRARY_VERSION` appropriately when building your application.

Comment: well,
first, Thanks for the answer. but I'll build the application on my machine and the user will use the exe according to his environment so the #if will only work during compilation. suppose that I have the latest version is installed so it will work on my machine but the user will have the linking error if he uses old version as he has the exe from me only 
what do you think ?

Comment: Option 1: Ask users to download the latest version of the third party library. Option 2: Distribute the latest version of the third part library with your .exe. Opton 3: Build two versions of your .exe and make sure that each of your users is able to pick which version they choose to use.